# How to stop WebRequest use last successful credential - reset CredentialCache

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2015, webrequest, .net-4.5.2

When using the following code, if I specify a wrong username/password combination I get a 407 error.

If I use a correct one, I get the page requested.

If I try again with a wrong username/password I get a normal response.

For some reason, WebRequest caches the proxy's username/password (CredentialCache) combination for the requested URL. If I change the URL pointing to a different domain, I get a proper 407.

How can I stop WebRequest from using last successful credential?

```
    Dim request As WebRequest = WebRequest.Create("http://contoso.com")

    request.Proxy = New WebProxy("http://myproxy:8080")
    Dim username = InputBox("Username")
    Dim password = InputBox("Password")
    request.Proxy.Credentials = New NetworkCredential(username, password)

    Try
        Using response = request.GetResponse()
            ' Display the status.
            txt_response.Text = CType(response, HttpWebResponse).StatusDescription & "Response is from cache?: " & response.IsFromCache
            ' Get the stream containing content returned by the server.
            Dim dataStream As Stream = response.GetResponseStream()
            ' Open the stream using a StreamReader for easy access.
            Dim reader As New StreamReader(dataStream)
            ' Read the content.
            Dim responseFromServer As String = reader.ReadToEnd()
            ' Display the content.
            txt_Result.Text = responseFromServer
            ' Clean up the streams and the response.
            reader.Close()
            response.Close()
        End Using
    Catch ex As WebException
        txt_response.Text = ex.Status & ": " & ex.Message
    End Try
```